# Synthesis of Aspirin

Tags: organic-chemistry

In my lab experiment for the synthesis of Aspirin we used hot water to quench the reaction. Why wouldn't we use cold water but hot water?

Comment: You used an excess of acetic anhydride, and you want to hydrolize the unreacted fraction. The hydrolysis reaction proceeds faster at higher temperatures.

Comment: In a commercial environment and larger lab scale, quenching of water sensitive reagents at too cold a temperature can lead to accumulation and then thermal runaway. Phosphorous oxychloride is notorious for this. It's sometimes safer to quench at warmer temperatures for the reason The_Vinz said, but it can be a balance.